# How can I capture a Java String from a DOM element?

Tags: java

**NOTE**: edited by @drachenstern, and I don't mind removing my answer on account of this. The OP is <strike>Russian (I believe)</strike> *Ukrainian* (with my apologies) and is having an ESL issue describing his problem. Between the two HRs is his original post.

---

order that would make getElementsByTagName ("s"); and give value = '2d331be47563423424abdb7fe2eee6401c7b00417'

my string:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=windows-1251' />
  </head>
  <body onload="try { document.getElementById('l').submit(); } catch(e) { document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit(); }">
    <form id='l' method='post' action='http://vkontakte.ru/login.php'>
      <input type='hidden' name='s' value='2d331be47563423424abdb7fe2eee6401c7b00417' />
            <input type='hidden' name='op' value='slogin' />
      <input type='hidden' name='redirect' value='1' />
      <input type='hidden' name='expire' value='0' />
      <input type='hidden' name='to' value='' />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need Convert String to DOM model order that would make parsing

I write this is my String in Java!

```
String mystr = "<html....</html>";
```

Russian - "У меня есть строка в JAVA она содержит в себе html файл(страницу сайта). Мне нужна функция которая достанет value в input. Я знаю что это можно прекрасно сделать через DOM модель, но у меня не получается это сделать."

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource( new StringReader( body ) );
Document d = builder.parse( is );
String ss = d.getElementById("s").getNodeValue(); //- null
```

---

He understands the way to parse for an element in Javascript is via something like `getElementsByTagName('s');` and he wants to find the equivalent way to do this in Java. He doesn't know what library he needs. For what it's worth, I don't write Java either. He can only explain one metaphor with another tho.

Google translates his Russian request as:

> I have a string in JAVA it contains
>   the html file (page). I need a
>   function that would get value in the
>   input. I know that this can be done
>   well through the DOM model, but I did
>   not get to do it.

Comment: Replaced `java` tag with `javascript`.  The two are completely different.

Comment: It sounds like this is the content of a Java String object, and the OP wants to parse out tag values similar to javascript...

Comment: What is the getElementsByTagName bit about?

Comment: Insist all you want.  This question is Javascript, not Java.  I replaced the tag.

Comment: @SimplyDenis - Please visit this URL http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-general

Comment: @ErickRobertson hence I'm going to delete my responses in large part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML string will not be any more complicated than this, then the easiest solution is just to parse with a Regular Expression, like

```
name='s' value='(.*?)'
```

Comment: But that's not a gaurantee that it will be the only match found. Granted, you could have an array of returned values, but still. And to begin with, I think that he's using this for auth effects, when there are plenty of libraries that do that for you invisibly on the callstack that work with cookies. DRY is a useful principle for a reason. As is NIH.

Comment: @drachenstern - good point.  I think we're all struggling to understand here :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that he is calling `getElementById` where the element has **name='s' NOT id='s'**. I would suggest calling `getElementsByTagName` instead and then looping through the returned list of input nodes to find what is needed.